# Using js to pull specific xml data

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a site that will pull xml nodes into html using *xmlhttprequest*.

I want to display the data in tables, the problem lies in selecting between the two different nodes.

In my xml I have two nodes. **filmsincinemas** and **filmsfuturereleases**, which both have 4 child nodes. I have written javascript to read the xml file and pull in the **film** node and its child data, but it pulls in data for every film node. I want to be able to pull in **filmsincinemas** and **filmsfuturereleases** separately.

My XML is as follows ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xmlRoot>
    <filmplaylist>
        <filmsincinemas>
            <film>
                <name><![CDATA[Film 1]]></name>
                <website>http://www.movielink.com/</website>
                <video>trailer1.flv</video>
                <hd></hd>
            </film>
            <film>
                <name><![CDATA[Film 2]]></name>
                <website>http://www.movielink.com/</website>
                <video>trailer2.flv</video>
                <hd></hd>
            </film>
            <film>
                <name><![CDATA[Film 3]]></name>
                <website>http://www.movielink.com/</website>
                <video>trailer3.flv</video>
                <hd></hd>
            </film>
        </filmsincinemas>
        <filmsfuturereleases>
            <film>
                <name><![CDATA[Film 4]]></name>
                <website>http://www.movielink.com/</website>
                <video>trailer4.flv</video>
                <hd>trailer4hd.flv</hd>
            </film>
            <film>
                <name><![CDATA[Film 5]]></name>
                <website>http://www.movielink.com/</website>
                <video>trailer5.flv</video>
                <hd>trailer5hd.flv</hd>
            </film>
            <film>
                <name><![CDATA[Film 6]]></name>
                <website>http://www.movielink.com/</website>
                <video>trailer6.flv</video>
                <hd>trailer6hd.flv</hd>
            </film>
        </filmsfuturereleases>
    </filmplaylist>
</xmlRoot>
```

My html/js is as follows ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>XML test</title>

<!-- XML Connect -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/main.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
</script>
<!-- XML Connect END -->

</head>

<body>

<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">

        <script>

        //Set X Var to parent node
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("film");

        //'For each' loop
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
            //Begin Table Row and TD
            document.write("<tr><td>");

            //If Node is empty
            if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("website")[0].childNodes.length == 0) {
                //Print space
                document.write("&nbsp;")
                } else {
                    //Print node
                    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("website")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            //Close row and TD
            document.write("</td><td>");

            //Same loop as previous
            if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes.length) {
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                } else {
                    x = "none"
                }
            //Close TD and Row
            document.write("</td></tr>");
            }

        </script>

    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript Code is not very good. But it seems to be very simple to accomplish what you want. This should work.

```js
function getTable(xmlDoc){
    //Set X Var to parent node
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("film");
    //'For each' loop
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
        //Begin Table Row and TD
        document.write("<tr><td>");

        //If Node is empty
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("website")[0].childNodes.length == 0) {
            //Print space
            document.write("&nbsp;")
            } else {
                //Print node
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("website")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
        //Close row and TD
        document.write("</td><td>");

        //Same loop as previous
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes.length) {
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            } else {
                x = "none"
            }
        //Close TD and Row
        document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
}

// Will print filmsfuturereleases
getTable(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filmsfuturereleases")[0]);

// Will print filmsincinemas
getTable(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filmsincinemas")[0]);
```

Comment: If you're willing to share more than 'your javascript code is not very good', how can it be improved?

Comment: Sorry for the poor input. You should get rid of that document.write calls. They're evil and won't work if you try to call the function after the page have finished loading. Try to use jQuery or a similar library to update the HTML code via DOM.

Comment: No worries. Ok, like $("body").append('write stuff here');?

Comment: That's an option. A better approach is to write the empty list `<ul id="filmsfuturereleases"></ul>` to the page, and then add <li> to it like this. `$('#filmsfuturereleases').append('<li>list item number one</li>')`. Or something similar with table rows instead of list items

Comment: Nice one, I'll go with this option. Thanks for your help!